# Sign psbt with software wallet. [electrum & others]

Tags: wallet, electrum, bip174-psbt

So I've been looking for days to sign a PSBT transaction but upon to all my research i failed or i just haven't searched in the right place.

The PSBT content is generated from a payment gateway that I've been using for my web services  named btcpaymerchant.com and it provides me a version of the PSBT encoded and decoded with inputs/outputs/txid/pubkey/etc..

I only need to sign  it from what i understood I've tried importing the file to electrum but it doesn't let me to sign it , when attempting to sign it the button to sign it is disabled.

•What i tried:

- Tried directly importing the PSBT content to electrum and saving it to transaction history and proceeding to sign it but electrum disables the buttons to sign automatically when opening the transaction.
- Steps i took on electrum to import the PSBT to wallet are:
  Tools -> Load Transaction -> From File/From Text -> Save
  Then the transaction appears as local [rbf] without allowing me to sign it it,
  image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvWA4.jpg
- Tried using coinb.in to sign/verify the transaction no success.
- Different wallets and wallets type from bip32->44->49.
- When trying to import https://coinb.ib encoded transaction to electrum it results in error `scriptsig-not-pushonly` [image of the error:  https://imgur.com/bnx5LZV ]
- I also tried researching the shit out of this and how to do it for 3 days.

•Most of you may ask why didn't i contacted support?
That's a good point i tried but they haven't responded, i read the documentation several times but still no success.
I ve also read the documentation for the wallet and psbt for like 20 times [https://docs.btcpayserver.org/Wallet/].

They offer the following steps for PSBT transactions.

- A PSBT gets constructed with certain inputs and outputs, but no signatures
- The exported PSBT can be imported by a wallet that supports this format
- The transaction data can be inspected and signed using the wallet
- The signed PSBT file gets exported from the wallet and imported with BTCPay Server
- BTCPay Server produces the final Bitcoin transaction
- You verify the result and broadcast it to the network

Most of the people use hardware wallets to sign these transactions but currently i do not own one if you have any other suggestions of software wallets that could help me out im all ears.
Thanks for your attention and helping!

What exactly needs to be signed?

- The whole transaction?
- The inputs or outputs?
- Or anything?

How do you merge the signatures  with the message?

- I know there is a setting "merge signatures from" while viewing the transaction but for me it results in a parsing error :
  Electrum was unable to parse your transaction: ValueError('failed to recognize transaction encoding for txt:...)

The payment gateway that generates the PSBT also provides the features combine psbt which from my guess lets you combine 2 PSBT i tried encoding the signature and merging it but no success.

The payment gateway also provides a demo at https://mainnet.demo.btcpayserver.org if anyone is intrested.

The payment also has 1 or multiple inputs and 1/2 outputs.